# PrestaShop virtual product file upload using web service

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am adding virtual product in PrestaShop using API and I am using [PSWebServiceLibrary](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php)

I have successfully added product and its images but when I am trying to add file to download for this product, I didn't find any method in above library and API.

So, I need any method to add downloadable file for virtual products in PrestaShop using API.

Comment: Hi swati did you find a solution?